# Linear time algorithm for finding SSSP when updating the weight only one edge

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Say I have a strongly connected directed graph with weights (positive or negative) and w/o negative cycles that already has all the shortest path from s to v computed. Say I update one edge in the graph. Is there an algorithm close to linear time to find the SSSP from s once again on this new graph?

Comment: Nice exercise!  What are your thoughts on it?  This isn't a place we solve exercises for you.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: I guess I don't really know how to go about solving it. My understanding is that since one edge was changed, worst case scenario is that this changed edge might cause all shortest path to either deviate or go through the edge. That would mean that we would have to run Bellman ford once more, which cant possibly be in linear time. I was thinking about just running relaxation on each edge but im not sure how that would solve the problem.

Comment: Could it cause the shortest path to deviate *without* going through that updated edge?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little confused with your question. Say there is a shortest path, from s -> u -> v ->t going through the edge, (u,v). Say that we changed the weight of (u,v). Now we would have to check all edges going out of u to see if the shortest path to t still goes through (u,v)?

Comment: My current conclusion lies in 2 cases: Say (u,v) is the updated edge.
If the weight decreased, we go through all vertices and see if (u,v) is in the shortest path. If it is, then the shortest path doesnt change and if it's not in the shortest path, the shortest path is now s -> u -> v -> t. I'm not exactly sure what happens if the weight increases though.

Comment: To help you think more clearly, it might helpful to focus only on the case of "weight is decreased" and work out how to handle that situation, then once you've got that nailed down you can think about how to handle the "weight is increased" case.